# how to merge a list's element where every list element has three tuples?

Tags: list, scala, merge, tuples

I have this:

```
List(List("King",List("134"),"USA"),List("King",List("151","130"),"USA"))
```

I want this at last:

```
List("King",List("134","151","130"),"USA")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share some of your effort (code)?

Comment: ```List("King",List("151","130"),"USA")``` This is terrible. Don't do this. Scala will cast this to the closest common ancestor, ```Any``` in this case and you practically won't be able to do anything with it

Comment: You need to provide more examples. for instance, it is not clear what should happen if head of an inner list is "KING" and tail is "AUS".

Comment: i want if two elements have same head(King) and tail (USA), their body that is list should merge.

Comment: Since you say three *tuples* in your question title, but actually use `List` in the body, could you clarify? Was it meant to be 3-tuples inside the list or is it correct the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this exact Use Case you could use `Pattern Matching`:

```
val doubleList = List(List("King",List("134"),"USA"), List("King",List("151","130"),"USA"))
doubleList match {
  case (a :: (b:List[_]) :: c :: _) :: (_ :: (d:List[_]) :: _) :: _ => a :: (b ++ d) :: c :: Nil
  case other => println(s"Not expected: $other")
}
```

As you can see that is not so pretty, but with better names it may works for you.

Here some explanations:

- `a::b::c` represents a List, where a and b are the first two elements and c is the rest (tail)
- `_` are values you are not interested, in our case the tails and the type of the List.
- the rest composes your Lists and the result concatenates both sublists.

The result is as expected:

```
List(King, List(134, 151, 130), USA)
```

As mentioned in the comments you should change your data structure if you can.

Then it would be easier. For example:

```
case class MyObj(name: String, indices: List[String], country: String) {

  def merge(other: MyObj): MyObj =
     copy(indices = indices ++ other.indices)
}

val obj1 = MyObj("King",List("134"),"USA")
obj1.merge(MyObj("King",List("151","130"),"USA"))
```

This is way better to read.

**Update**: Solution for the comment:

You can use `groupBy` and then with `flatMap` concatenate the inner Lists:

```
 st.groupBy(e => (e._1, e._3))   // -> Map((COOK,ENG) -> List((COOK,List(100),ENG), ...)
    .map{ case ((n, c), list) => (n, list.flatMap(_._2), c)}
    .toList
    .sortBy(_._1)
```

This returns as expected: `List((COOK,List(100, 125, 135, 145),ENG), (KIM,List(115, 134, 148, 154),AUS), (TIM,List(102, 105),ZIM), (VIR,List(115, 120, 134),IND))`

`_._1` is how you access entries of a tuple.

**Update 2**: Keep sorting

This is possible but AFAIK it gets complex. I am not sure if this is readable enough:

```
st
  .zipWithIndex // add an index for later sorting
  .groupBy { case (e, _) => (e._1, e._3) }
  .map { case ((n, c), groupedList) => (n,
    groupedList.map { case (trible, index) => (trible._2, index) } // you are only interested in the list and the index
      .foldLeft((List.empty[String], Int.MaxValue)) { case ((list1, i1), (list2, i2)) =>
        (list1 ++ list2, Math.min(i1, i2)) // fold over all the lists and take the minimal index
      }
    , c)
  }.toList
  .sortBy { case (_, (_, index), _) => index } // sort the result by the index
  .map { case (n, (list, _), c) => (n, list, c) } // get rid of the index
```

Comment: How to do this when   the list contains more than 2 elements like

Comment: List(("VIR",List("115"),"IND"),("KIM",List("115"),"AUS"),("COOK",List("100"),"ENG"),("VIR",List("120","134"),"IND"),("KIM",List("134","148","154"),"AUS"),("COOK",List("125","135","145"),"ENG"),("TIM",List("102","105"),"ZIM"))

and i want merging of 2nd tuple based on first and third and also order of the list should not break

Like for the above list final list :
List(("VIR",List("115","120","134"),"IND"),("KIM",List("115","134","148","154"),"AUS"),("COOK",List("100","125","135","145"),"ENG"),("TIM",List("102","105"),"ZIM"))

Comment: thanks!!  one more thing by this method I am getting final list as per the first element's alphabetical order but I want order to be same with the prior list like if my list is :::List(("VIR",List("115"),"IND"),("KIM",List("115"),"AUS"),("COOK",List("100"),"ENG"),("VIR",List("120","134"),"IND"),("KIM",List("134","148","154"),"AUS"),("COOK",List("125","135","145"),"ENG"))

Comment: finally the list should be :::List(("VIR",List("115","120","134"),"IND"),("KIM",List("115","134","148","154"),"AUS"),("COOK",List("100","125","135","145"),"ENG"),("TIM",List("102","105"),"ZIM"))

Comment: that is list should start with "VIR" it doesn't mean that order should be reversed I want order like original list mean if it starts with VIR end list should also start with VIRand then afterward merging

Comment: can we do so ? I think groupby will change the order. Do we have any other option to solve this poblem ?

Comment: @AnandSharma see my updated answer but I think you must have a good reason to keep the sorting.

Comment: Great! consider also to upvote an answer that helped you;).